# Slim 3 problem with the routes in subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I have an app with the following structure:

```
App/
|— app/
    |— config
    |— controllers
    |— middlewares
    |— routes
         |— routes.php
    |— views
    |— app.php
    |— autoload.php
|— public/
    |—.htaccess
    |— index.php
|— vendor/
```

Ok, in the .htaccess on the /public folder contain the following (from the Slim docs):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And the index.php on the /public folder contain the following:

```
define('BASE_ROOT',dirname(__DIR__) . '/');
require_once BASE_ROOT.'app/app.php';
$app->run();
```

So, we go to the app/app.php file:

```
<?php
require BASE_ROOT.'app/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => App\Config\Config::$config]); 

$container = $app->getContainer(); 
$container['view'] = function($container) {
  /*Set some configurations and environment vars*/
};

require BASE_ROOT.'app/routes/routes.php';
```

And finally, in the routes.php inside on app/routes/:

```
<?php

/*Routes*/
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $name = $args['name'];
  $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
});
```

I've put the 'hello world' route to simplify things, but the problem is that with any route registered in routes.php I receive 404 code...

I'm using apache server and the configuration on vhost is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\FranciscoSalazar\Desktop\PHP-SLIM\App\public"
    ServerName medo
    <Directory C:\Users\FranciscoSalazar\Desktop\PHP-SLIM\App\public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
I use:
 - PHP 7.3.2
 - Slim 3.0
 - Apache 2.4
```

If someone knows the answer or can guide me, I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: Are you sure you use composer properly? Because generated autoload usually will be inside vendor directory

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have two autoload.php, one inside the vendor folder and other inside the app folder, and the last one calls the previous one so It should be all right.

Comment: In routes.php, I believe you should add `use` for type Request and Response otherwise PHP will look Request and Response class in current namespace.

Comment: also make sure that mod_rewrite in Apache is enabled